# I keep hearing human sighs on Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing Minecraft almost my whole life and I've never heard what I'm hearing now. It's like a soft sigh, and I know it's on Minecraft since when I turned the sound off it would go away, and my mom and sister (who are home at the time) are too far away. It is right in my ears and it sounds maybe like a woman inhaling and exhaling every now and then. I made sure I didn't have any tabs open or apps open that could be making this sound. I'm pretty positive it's coming from Minecraft. Maybe there is a new update and the animals have an extremely human like sigh? Is this normal or am I going crazy?

Comment: Do you have any mods on?

Comment: When you hear the sound next, try muting minecraft and see if it continues.

Comment: Do you have a recording?

Answer (score 4):

It may be a ghast, either in the nether, or it escaped through a portal (I am not sure if they can do that, but if they can, then that would be possible).

Turn on subtitles and look what they say while you hear that sound, to turn on subtitles go to the settings, "Options...", "Accessibility settings...", "Show Subtitles".

Try if you can hear it in every dimension (overworld, nether, and end).

Try if you can hear it in peaceful mode.

Comment: If this does not help, please activate subtitles and take a screenshot while you hear the sound

Comment: It wasn't quite like a ghast, and i was in peaceful mode but that's a good idea to put on subtitles, i'll definitely try that! Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure out what it was?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not the only one, it seems.
I heard it about five minutes ago while on a Realm.

Do note that I have not played Minecraft for a very long time and only recently started playing again. In fact, the last version of Minecraft I played was around version 1.7 or so.

Anyway, after doing a little bit of research, I stumbled upon Ambiences. Take a look at the following link and expand the list.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ambience#Cave_ambience

My guess is that what we had heard is Cave 4, but played from extremely far away and/or softly.

Comment: I think this is very likely. It might be because of a cave under your base or something. I hate those sounds.

Answer (score 0):

my minecraft game was completely silent and like it litteraly BREATHED it sounded like somebody breathing, i just started my minecraft world was just made, and the sound WAS OFF and i was on peacefull mode
so it couldnt of been a ghast, cave sound, or a mod that i accidentaly put on
im scared...

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This is not what answers are meant for. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.